# Managing player data

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a code example from my name, where I use a MySQL db and store players data.

In this code I'm using a `DataReader` when loading and saving the data in and out. Although there's only 10 fields, I have reduced the number for this example. I plan on having 50+.

The main focus of this question is to find a more efficient way of managing players' data, a way that doesn't require so much code and hard work to load / save it.

Adding new features is a pain as I have to code a whole new set of fields to load and save, not forgetting the features.

My only idea was to make a dict and load it as `[columnName] = columnValue;`, cache it, grab if loaded previously and save all items on save. The problem with that was I didn't like the fact I had to explicitly call by the columns name. What if I changed it?

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Pitaya.Game.Players.Data
{
    internal class PlayerData
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Username;
        public int Rank;
        public string Motto;
        public PlayerOutfit Outfit;
        public PlayerGender Gender;
        public long Credits;
        public long Pixels;
        public long Diamonds;
        public bool CanChange;



        public void AssignData(MySqlDataReader reader)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Id = reader.GetInt32("id");
                Username = reader.GetString("username");
                Rank = reader.GetInt32("rank");
                Motto = reader.GetString("motto");
                Outfit = new PlayerOutfit(reader.GetString("look"));
                Gender = reader.GetString("gender").ToUpper() == "M" ? PlayerGender.Male : PlayerGender.Female;
                Credits = reader.GetInt64("credits");
                Pixels = reader.GetInt64("activity_points");
                Diamonds = reader.GetInt64("vip_points");
                CanChange = reader.GetInt32("can_change") == 1;
            }
        }

        public void SaveData()
        {
            using (var dbConnection = Program.Server.Database.Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.SetQuery("UPDATE `users` SET `username` = @username, `rank` = @rank, `motto = @motto, `look` = @look, `gender` = @gender, `credits` = @credits, `pixels` = @pixels, `diamonds` = @diamonds, `can_change` = @canChange WHERE `id` = @id");
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("id", Id);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("username", Username);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("rank", Rank);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("motto", Motto);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("look", Outfit.FigureCode);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("gender", Gender == PlayerGender.Male ? "M" : "F");
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("credits", Credits);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("pixels", Pixels);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("diamonds", Diamonds);
                dbConnection.AppendParameter("canChange", CanChange ? 1 : 0);
                dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a lot of fields, I would suggest using a `DataTable` where each column is a field.  This not only keeps your data organized and easily accessible, but you can very efficiently write the data to a database, and display the data in a `DataGridView`, which also gives you ready access to methods for adding and editing the data.